# Programmatically emulating Photoshop shape transformations to automate overlaying images over other images

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, e-commerce

The task I'm stuck with is finding a way to approach creating multiple product images having same image overlayed over them - that is, different clothes with a print. Overlaying image and blending it with other seem like a managable task using Python and OpenCV, the problem comes when I need to use complex shape transformation, like in the image below.

[image]

The overlaying image should take the white rectangle's shape, it seems somewhat trivial task in Photoshop, but is it at all possible using OpenCV and feasible considering there would be many such shapes for different clothes? Or should I approach the problem in a different way, say, trying to emulate what designer does in Photoshop using GIMP and running it as a CLI tool? Sadly I can't use Photoshop itself since processing has to happen on a webserver.

Maybe someone knows how this problem is generally solved on online stores that specialise in selling clothes with prints on them? Usually there's huge variety of different templates with one print on them, surely they aren't creating and uploading them manually, it has to be automated.

Comment: I think you will need something like 2D spline deformation techniques. Have a look at https://github.com/hboyadzhieva/deforming-techniques and https://github.com/ssloy/instantangle

Comment: @Micka Thanks, that seems like a possible way to go.